# Spring ApplicationContext and BeanFactory

Tags: java, spring, memory-management

Spring Application Context will loads all Singleton beans at the time of Server StartUp . But in the case of big application , it has loaded many objects into memory .Won't it be the performance bottleneck in the application, Won't it gather the space on the Heap /permanent Space in the heap .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of design choice you as a programmer have to take - yes the objects will occupy memory - yes they are eagerly instantiated. How much memory these objects will occupy depends upon what they contain - it could be small or it could be huge. Whether its a good thing or bad depends on what your program does.

Just equally true is that Spring also supports lazy initialization of beans

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.foo.SomeBean" lazy-init="true"/>
```

Comment: You can also force ALL beans to lazy load. See here http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't be what causes your memory problems, unless you're running on some embedded system with tiny memory space. "Many objects" in this context is maybe a few hundred or a few thousand at most. That adds up to virtually nothing with today's memory allocations.